# checkbox is always pushed to the right even when padding is set to 0

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to setup a simple UI as follows:

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun Confirmation() {
    Column(
        modifier =
        Modifier.padding(start=0.dp),
    ) {
    Text(text= "Text")
    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,

    ) {

        Checkbox(
            checked = true,
            onCheckedChange = {},
        )
        Text(

            text = "Sign Me up",
            fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.caption.fontSize,
        )
    }
}
```

and it gives me the following UI

[image: CURRENT UI]

but I want the checkbox to start on the left of the column just like the Text above it. For now, the Row or rather the checkbox (if I replace the checkbox with Text, it is okay) appears to have a margin-left that pushes it inside/to the right. Basically I want something like this:

Text
checkbox checkbox_label

instead of

Text
checkbox checkbox_label

Comment: Its because CheckBox component internally uses `TriStateCheckbox` which has ripple radius of 24.dp. And it can be removed only if you set `onCheckedChange = null` or create custom `CheckboxComponent`

Comment: oh that explains it!!!

Comment: So creating custom checkbox component would help you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom `TriStateCheckbox` instead of `material` one:

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun Confirmation() {
    Column(
        modifier =
        Modifier.padding(start = 0.dp),
    ) {
        Text(text = "Text")
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,

            ) {

            var isChecked by remember {
                mutableStateOf(true)
            }
            CustomCheckbox(
                checked = isChecked,
                onCheckedChange = {
                    isChecked = it
                }
            )
            Text(

                text = "Sign Me up",
                fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.caption.fontSize,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun CustomCheckbox(
    checked: Boolean,
    onCheckedChange: ((Boolean) -> Unit)?,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    colors: CheckboxColors = CheckboxDefaults.colors()
) {
    TriStateCheckbox(
        state = ToggleableState(checked),
        onClick = null,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        enabled = enabled,
        colors = colors,
        modifier = modifier.triStateToggleable(
            state = ToggleableState(checked),
            onClick = {
                if (onCheckedChange != null) {
                    run { onCheckedChange(!checked) }
                }
            },
            enabled = enabled,
            role = Role.Checkbox,
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            indication = null
        )
    )
}
```

[image]